# Picasso won't show image from imgur

Tags: android, picasso

This is the code i use, the library is imported from the jar, the image link works fine and i even added the internet permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml. 
The problem is that when i start the app it opens and closes without showing anything.

```
package my.pkg.name;

import com.squareup.picasso.*;
import android.R.id.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.id.immagine);
        ImageView targetImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.immagine);
        String internetUrl = "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png";

        Picasso
            .with(this)
            .load(internetUrl)
            .into(targetImageView);
       }  
}
```

And this is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="just a string"
    />
<ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/immagine"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:contentDescription="213"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Could you post your stack trace as well? :)

Comment: @CommonsWare it really doesn't look like a crash, it's most likely an error in the code. Thanks for the answer though

Comment: @YussufSassi even if it is an error in the code, you still should have the error in the logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setContentView(R.id.immagine);` is wrong. Usually you put `R.layout.something` into `setContentView`.

Comment: thanks @GeorgiKoemdzhiev. OP Yussuf Sassi pls accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: It was @YussufSassi that asked the question :p

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember, except that `Layout` as @eriuzo said, that could be due to `Activity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

For these situations, you should check the logcats if something is wrong.but, You can use that with `AppCompatActivity` that should solve the problem.